# Cordova app form input fields lagging in showing data while entering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have created a **cordova** app using **node, angular, sqlite**. The app consist of **multipage** form. When i fill the form then **input fields are lagging** means **they are taking time to show the entered data**. Can anyone tell me the reasons why these issues comes. 
My farm page is quite big means it consist large no. of fields which are divided in  four parts and i am showing them 1 by 1 after by making others hide and then submitting it in the end.

this is the form

```
<form name="signupForm" data-ng-submit="gotoAddress()">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12  top-bottom-border"> <span class="heading">Personal Info</span>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
            <label class="form-tags-info-page" for="name">Name</label>
            <br>
            <input class="form-control" id="input-elements-info-page" placeholder="name" type="text" name="ufname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s\,]{1,100}$/" ng-model="myForm.name" required>
            <div class="help-block" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off">
                <p style="color: red" ng-show="signupForm.ufname.$dirty && signupForm.ufname.$touched && signupForm.ufname.$error.required">Name is required</p>
                <p style="color: red" ng-show="signupForm.ufname.$dirty && signupForm.ufname.$touched && signupForm.ufname.$error.pattern">Enter a valid Name</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 remove-all-padding">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-6 remove-all-padding age-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && signupForm.age.$invalid }">
                <label class="form-tags-info-page" for="age">Age(in year)</label>
                <br>
                <input name="age" class="form-control" id="input-elements-info-page" type="number" ng-model="myForm.age" min="14" max="120" required>
                <span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.age.$dirty && signupForm.age.$invalid">
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.age.$error.required">Required!</span>
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.age.$error.min">Minimum 14</span>
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.age.$error.max">Invalid Age!</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-6 remove-all-padding sex-group pull-right">
                <label class="form-tags-info-page" for="sex">Sex</label>
                <br>
                <select class="form-control" id="input-elements-info-page" ng-model="myForm.sex" required>
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Sex</option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && signupForm.ownership.$invalid }">
            <label class="form-tags-info-page">Ownership</label>
            <select name="ownership" data-ng-model="myForm.ownership" id="input-elements-info-page" placeholder="Select Annual Income" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="" selected disabled>Select Ownership</option>
                <option value="Owner">Owner</option>
                <option value="Successor">Successor</option>
                <option value="Blood-relative">Blood-relative</option>
                <option value="Contract-farmer">Contract-farmer</option>
            </select>
            <div ng-show="submitted && signupForm.ownership.$invalid" class="help-block">
                <p ng-show="signupForm.ownership.$error.required">Annual Income is required</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-tags-info-page" for="name">Father's Name</label>
            <br>
            <input class="form-control" id="input-elements-info-page" placeholder="father's name" type="text" name="fname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s\,]{1,100}$/" ng-model="myForm.fathername" required>
            <div class="help-block">
                <p style="color: red" ng-show="signupForm.fname.$dirty && signupForm.fname.$touched && signupForm.fname.$error.required">Father's Name is required</p>
                <p style="color: red" ng-show="signupForm.fname.$dirty && signupForm.fname.$touched && signupForm.fname.$error.pattern">Enter a valid Father's Name</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && signupForm.mobile_no.$invalid }">
            <label class="form-tags-info-page" for="mobile">Mobile Number</label>
            <br>
            <input class="form-control" id="input-elements-info-page" type="number" name="mobile_no" placeholder="Mobile No" ng-model="myForm.mobile_no" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}/" required>
            <span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.mobile_no.$dirty && signupForm.mobile_no.$invalid">
                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.mobile_no.$error.required">Required!</span>
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.mobile_no.$error.minlength">Too short!</span>
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.mobile_no.$error.maxlength">Too long!</span>
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.mobile_no.$error.pattern">Invalid Mobile Number</span>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && signupForm.alt_mobile_no.$invalid }">
            <label class="form-tags-info-page" for="mobile">Alternate Mobile Number</label>
            <br>
            <input class="form-control" id="input-elements-info-page" type="number" name="alt_mobile_no" placeholder="Alternate Mobile No" ng-model="myForm.alt_mobile_no" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}/" required>
            <span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.alt_mobile_no.$dirty && signupForm.alt_mobile_no.$invalid">
                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.alt_mobile_no.$error.required">Required!</span>
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.alt_mobile_no.$error.minlength">Too short!</span>
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.alt_mobile_no.$error.maxlength">Too long!</span>
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="signupForm.alt_mobile_no.$error.pattern">Invalid Mobile Number</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-tags-info-page" for="email">Email Id(optional)</label>
            <br>
            <input class="form-control" id="input-elements-info-page" placeholder="Email" type="email" ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$/" ng-model="myForm.email">
            <div class="help-block">
                <p style="color: red" ng-show="signupForm.email.$dirty && signupForm.email.$touched && signupForm.email.$error.pattern">Enter a valid email address</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-tags-info-page" for="size">Family Size</label>
            <br>
            <select class="form-control" id="input-elements-info-page" ng-model="myForm.family_size" required>
                <option value="" selected disabled>Select Family Size</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">&gt;10</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <form class="form-inline col-sm-12 col-xs-12 remove-all-padding">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-6 age-group remove-all-padding">
                <label class="form-tags-info-page" for="land">LandArea</label>
                <br>
                <input class="form-control" id="input-elements-info-page" style="width:100%;" type="number" required ng-model="myForm.l_area">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-6 remove-all-padding sex-group pull-right">
                <label class="form-tags-info-page" for="size">Unit</label>
                <br>
                <select class="form-control" id="input-elements-info-page" style="width:100%;" ng-model="myForm.area_unit" required>
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Unit</option>
                    <option value="Acre">Acre</option>
                    <option value="Hactare">Hactare</option>
                    <option value="Bigha">Bigha</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-tags-info-page" for="size">Language Preference</label>
            <br>
            <select class="form-control" id="input-elements-info-page" ng-model="myForm.language" required>
                <option value="" selected disabled>Select Language</option>
                <option value="english">English</option>
                <option value="hindi">Hindi</option>
                <option value="others">Others</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <form class="form-inline col-sm-12 col-xs-12 remove-all-padding">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-6 remove-all-padding ">
                <label class="form-tags-info-page col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="uid_type">ID Type</label>
                <br>
                <select class="form-control col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="input-elements-info-page" style="width:100%;" ng-model="myForm.farmerid_type">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select id Type</option>
                    <option value="Aadhar">Aadhar</option>
                    <option value="VoterID">VoterID</option>
                    <option value="Driving Licence">Driving Licence</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-6 remove-all-padding sex-group">
                <label class="form-tags-info-page" for="uid_no">ID No.</label>
                <br>
                <input class="form-control" id="input-elements-info-page" type="text" style="width:100%;" ng-model="myForm.farmeruid_no" required>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 remove-all-padding">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 camera-img-wrapp">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> <span ng-click="takePic()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera camera-pic"></span>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> <span ng-click="takeScan();" class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera camera-pic"></span>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">
                    <p class="form-tags-info-page">Take Pic</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">
                    <p class="form-tags-info-page">Take Scan</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12 remove-all-padding" ng-show="imageSrc || scanSrc">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2"> <span ng-show="imageSrc"><img src="" id="myImage" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></span>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2"> <span ng-show="scanSrc"><img src="" id="myScan" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="btn-group btn-next">
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Next">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

on creating android app fields name,fathername are lagging. they are showing the data we are entering after few seconds which is too much.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi i have posted the html file in which issue in coming..

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not going into very much detail with your question, I cant go into detail with my answer.

Ill try to explain where your issues might come from and adjust my answer if you provide more information:

Cordova uses WebView container in a native App which basicly uses the same engine for rendering as your mobile browser. The performance bottleneck of browsers is accessing of DOM elements (causing reflow and rerendering). Therefore you have to be very aware of the performance issues it can create communicating with DOM api. If Your DOM changes take more than 16 ms to render your application becomes visibly slow and sluggish. Going down from 60 fps your performance issues get more and more obvious to the user.

Since mobile devices are alot slower than desktop computers you will have to be very cautious about alot of things.

There are alot of performance hacks you can apply to your mobile web app.

here are some: https://quickleft.com/blog/4-steps-to-minimizing-rendering-issues-in-cordova-applications/

With [ReactJs](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and overuse of CSS transitions you can achive ~60fps applications that almost seem to be native. I have made good experiences with this.

EDIT1: My Hint:
rebuild your Frontend with ReactJs and avoid overuse of frameworks. Keep your DOM structure clean and do animations with CSS (try to avoid js based animations as much as you can!). Measure your FPS while you develop and find performance issues straight away. To build a nice performant nativelike app you will find no way arround this approach.

I hope this helped.

Comment: page are changing appropriately the main issue is input fields aren't showing the data which we are entering simultaneously it is taking time to show them.

Comment: well should I start guessing to get more accurate? You havent even applied on line of code. The initial DOM structure will most likely have nothing to do with your issue.